# FORFILES + COPY in Batch does not collect Data I need

Tags: batch-file, copy

I want to collect data with "_CPU2" in the name to the folder collected_data.
My batch creates a directory, says that files are copied, but the directory is empty. Please point me to my mistakes, and what I shold improve.

```
if not exist "%~dp0\collected_data" MKDIR collected_data
SET data_folder="%~dp0%collected_data"

FORFILES /M *_CPU2* /S /C "cmd /c COPY @file %data_folder%
```

Comment: Does it tell you how many files were copied? And have you tried adding an `echo` in front of all the lines to see which commands are produced?

Comment: You actually do not need the `if exist` line, simply write `2> nul mkdir "%data_folder%"` after the `set` command line; the `2> nul` portion suppresses the error message if the directory already exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps because you are recursing into sub directories you'll be better advised to use the full path and not just the file name:

```bat
PAUSE 
SET "data_folder=%~dp0collected_data"
IF NOT EXIST "%data_folder%\" MKDIR "%data_folder%"
FORFILES /M *_CPU2* /S /C "CMD /C COPY @path 0x22%data_folder%0x22"
PAUSE
```

Comment: Thank you. Youre skript is doing it perfect! What does mean "0x22"?

Comment: It is the hexadecimal code for the double quote, which is considered a special character in the forfiles command line.